# How can I sum up number from JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this following example of JSON. I want to sum up `'numberOfPoint'` corresponding to `'Name'` to get the total number of points. In this case, name A has total number of point 6, name B has total number of point 2, and name C has total number of point 2.

```
{ "data": [
    {
        "id": {
            "year": 2015,
            "Name": "A"
        },
        "numberOfPoint": 2
    },
    {
        "id": {
            "year": 2014,
            "Name": "A"
        },
        "numberOfPoint": 2
    },
    {
        "id": {
            "year": 2014,
            "Name": "B"
        },
        "numberOfPoint": 2
    },
    {
        "id": {
            "year": 2014,
            "Name": "C"
        },
        "numberOfPoint": 2
    },
    {
        "id": {
            "year": 2013,
            "Name": "A"
        },
        "numberOfPoint": 2
    }]
}
```

How can I sum up the `numberOfPoint` for each name? A pure JavaScript or jQuery solution is fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Solution

The following solution should work fine assuming **`obj` is your JSON**.

```
var result = {};

obj.data.forEach(function (a) { result[a["id"]["Name"]] = (result[a["id"]["Name"]] || 0) + a["numberOfPoint"]; });
```

`result` is where the values will be stores. `result` will look something like:

```
{
    "A": 6,
    "B": 2,
    "C": 2
}
```

### Explanation

This is simple once you are able to 'deobfuscate it'. First the object (`result`) is defined. Then we loop through all the items in `obj.data`. Next we find the `name` associated with the item and we put that as our key. Then we use an *OR* shorthand to see if it is defined to not, if not, set it to zero. Last, the value is added. This is repeated.

#### Update

Using `.reduce` looks nicer for this kind of thing:

```
obj.data.reduce(function (b,a) { return (b["id"]["Name"]] = (b[a["id"]["Name"]] || 0) + a["numberOfPoint"]) },{});
```

Answer (score 3):

I like using `reduce` for this kind of thing

```
yourObj.data.reduce(function(sums, elem) {
  var name = elem.id.Name;
  if (!sums[name]) sums[name] = 0;
  sums[name] += elem.numberOfPoint;
  return sums;
}, {});
```

Output

```
{A: 6, B: 2, C: 2}
```

---

A more functional approach might look like this

```
yourObj.data.map(function(elem) {
  return {key: elem.id.Name, value: elem.numberOfPoint};
}).reduce(function(sum, elem) {
  sum[elem.key] = (sum[elem.key] || 0) + elem.value;
  return sum;
}, {});
```

Output

```
{A: 6, B: 2, C: 2}
```

The advantage to this more decomposed approach is your function bodies are significantly less complex, easy to understand with just a quick glance, and more reusable

---

Here's what this might look like once we separate out the reusable bits

```
// create some reusable functions
function mapToKeyValue(obj) {
  return {key: obj.id.Name, value: obj.numberOfPoint};
}

function sumKeyValues(sum, obj) {
  sum[obj.key] = (sum[obj.key] || 0) + obj.value;
  return sum;
}

// now manipulate your data with ease
var result = yourObj.items.map(mapToKeyValue).reduce(sumKeyValues, {});
```

Output

```
{A: 6, B: 2, C: 2}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write a function like bellow

```
var sum = function(obj) {
    var result = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < obj.data.length; i++) {
        var element = obj.data[i];
        if (result[element.id.Name])
            result[element.id.Name] += element.numberOfPoint;
        else
            result[element.id.Name] = element.numberOfPoint;
    };
    return result;
};
```

And call that function like bellow

```
console.log(sum(givenData));
```

where `givenData` is the data given by you.

The output should be like bellow

```
{ A: 6, B: 2, C: 2 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Take with grain of salt.. I'm lazy.

```
var x = {...},
    sum = {};
x.data.forEach(function (elem) {
    var _sum = sum[elem.id.Name];
    if (!_sum) {
        _sum = 0;
    }
    _sum += parseInt(elem.numberOfPoint, 10);
});
```